# Inaccurate result of `eth_EstimateGas` on `call`

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I have the following contract which is used to execute a sequence of batched transactions using `CALL`

```
contract Test{
    function executeBatch(address[] calldata dest, bytes[] calldata func) external {
        _requireFromEntryPointOrOwner();
        require(dest.length == func.length, "wrong array lengths");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < dest.length; i++) {
            _call(dest[i], 0, func[i]);
        }
    }

    function _call(address target, uint256 value, bytes memory data) internal {
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = target.call{value : value}(data);
        if (!success) {
            assembly {
                revert(add(result, 32), mload(result))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And I tried to estimate gas cost of this function but find out that the estimated gas usage is inaccurate and result in `out of gas` after sending out the transaction.

The following is the testing script I used:

```
    kt20 := Interface.ABI("TestERC20")
    transfer20, err := kt20.Pack("transfer", receiver.Address().Address, big.NewInt(10000))
    s.Require().NoError(err)

    kt721 := Interface.ABI("TestERC721")
    transfer721, err := kt721.Pack("transferFrom", addrWallet.Address, receiver.Address().Address, token721)
    s.Require().NoError(err)

    kt1155 := Interface.ABI("TestERC1155")
    transfer1155, err := kt1155.Pack("safeTransferFrom", addrWallet.Address, receiver.Address().Address, token1155, big.NewInt(10), []byte{})
    s.Require().NoError(err)

    // estimate erc20
    callGas, err := s.aa.cli.EstimateGas(ctx, ethereum.CallMsg{
        From: addrWallet.Address,
        To:   &erc20Address,
        Data: transfer20,
    })
    s.Require().NoError(err)
    fmt.Println("erc20:", callGas)

    // estimate erc721
    callGas, err = s.aa.cli.EstimateGas(ctx, ethereum.CallMsg{
        From: addrWallet.Address,
        To:   &erc721Address,
        Data: transfer721,
    })
    s.Require().NoError(err)
    fmt.Println("erc721:", callGas)

    // estimate erc1155
    callGas, err = s.aa.cli.EstimateGas(ctx, ethereum.CallMsg{
        From: addrWallet.Address,
        To:   &erc1155Address,
        Data: transfer1155,
    })
    s.Require().NoError(err)
    fmt.Println("erc1155:", callGas)

    executeInput, err := s.accountImplmentation.Pack("executeBatch", []common.Address{
        erc20Address,
        erc721Address,
        erc1155Address,
    }, [][]byte{
        transfer20,
        transfer721,
        transfer1155,
    })
    s.Require().NoError(err)

    // estimate total execute gas
    callGas, err = s.aa.cli.EstimateGas(ctx, ethereum.CallMsg{
        From: owner.Address().Address,
        To:   &addrWallet.Address,
        Data: executeInput,
        Gas:  500000,
    })
    s.Require().NoError(err)
    fmt.Println("total:", callGas)
```

and the console output is as follows:

```
erc20: 51423
erc721: 60102
erc1155: 58985
total: 21600
```

as you can see, the total estimated gas is way lower than gas used by any single transaction included in `executeBatch`.

It seems that eth_EstimateGas cannot properly estimate the `CALL` gas usage.
So now the question is, is there a better way to estimate multiple `CALL` operation?

Thank you